# How can I hide hint in input form?

Tags: html, forms, input

[image]When I fill input login form, input form shows me previous login. How can I hide or don't display previous login.

I try to change type of input to `type = "hidden"`, but this hide was displayed like password type;

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for = "adminLogin">Login: </label>
    <input name = "adminLogin" type="hidden" >
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean previous login?

Comment: Do you wan't to clear input on submit?

Comment: `autocomplete="off"`?

Comment: Can you make us a screenshot?

Comment: You can add `autocomplete="off"` directly to the form too

Comment: @freeek yes sure

Comment: @VincentDecaux there is screenshot

Comment: @treyBake I mean, previous login is, all login, that I wrote before to this field

Comment: @bekanur98 When someone logs in, you redirect them to a new page, such as home or dashboard. Not sure what you mean here by previous login data still remains.

Comment: @vivek_23 if I will input login like vivek and press to submit, and after that, if I refresh this page and write letter ```v``` there will show hint like vivek, And this is previous login. But I don't want that displayed. Can I explain?

Comment: @bekanur98 So, for that you use `autocomplete="off"` in your input text field so that it doesn't show up previously filled values. See here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `autocomplete="off"` to tell the browser not to show suggestions:

```html
<form method="POST">
    <label for = "adminLogin">Login: </label>
    <input name = "adminLogin" autocomplete="off" >
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Comment: @bekanur98 this should work. Clear cache. You can also try for the whole form.

Comment: @bekanur98 clear you browser's cachec, there should be something about forms. May the google help you.

Comment: @freeek I am so sorry) It's work! Thank you very much